# Help in solving of probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $10^4$ students in university. They have 4 digit ids.
How many students do we have to invite into one class in order to observe at least 2 students with the same first two digits in id with probability more then 50%?

Could somebody point me to the way how to solve this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is actually birthday paradox. [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) gives full explanation of how to solve this type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $n$ students are invited then the probability that their first
two digits are all **distinct** is:

$$\frac{10000}{10000}.\frac{9900}{9999}.\frac{9800}{9998}.\cdots.\frac{100\times\left(101-n\right)}{10001-n}$$

Comment: What is the probability that some of them match?

Comment: $1$ minus the probability that there is no match. These events are complements of eachother.